# Early simple electric generators

Tags: electromagnetism

[image]

Can someone explain to me why it is B?

Is it because eddy currents are induced on the side of the disk, and since it is connected to Y it basically goes through Y to X etc? But it is also connected to X?

Exam tomorrow thanks !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a metal disk with free, mobile electrons. As the free electrons revolve with the disk, they feel a q(vxB) Lorentz force on them due to the magnetic field they pass through (where q=electron charge, v=velocity, and B=magnetic field). Use the right-hand rule to determine the direction of the cross-product. The v-vector points approximately into the page, while the B-field points from the N-pole to the S-pole, so the right-hand rule gives vxB as pointing downward. But since the q, the electron charge, is negative, the q(vxB) vector points upward. So the electrons move from point Y, then through the disk to point X, through the light bulb (or "globe"), and back to point Y (i.e., counter-clockwise through the circuit shown). But electrons are negatively charged, so the current flow is actually in the opposite direction (i.e., clockwise). Therefore, the current flows from point Y (and through the "globe") to point X, which is answer (B).

(P.S.: For the purposes of this problem of determining the direction of the current, you could have simply regarded the current carrying particles as being positively charged. Doing that would have also given you the right answer for the current direction but with fewer steps.)

Comment: just to confirm, we are both talking about the same right-hand rule because there are many? Right hand palm rule, right hand grip rule etc?

Comment: @silenceislive - I'm talking above about the "right hand rule" as used to determine the direction of a vector product (or cross product) of two vectors. See, for example, http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/vvec.html#vvc5 .

Answer (score 0):

A potential difference is created between the center of the disc and the rim (or ends of the cylinder) with an electrical polarity that depends on the direction of rotation and the orientation of the field.

The Faraday disc was primarily inefficient due to counterflows of current. While current flow was induced directly underneath the magnet, the current would circulate backwards in regions outside the influence of the magnetic field. This counterflow limits the power output to the pickup wires, and induces waste heating of the copper disc. Later homopolar generators would solve this problem by using an array of magnets arranged around the disc perimeter to maintain a steady field around the circumference, and eliminate areas where counterflow could occur

Comment: What do you mean by potential difference? Do you mean eddy currents? So eddy currents are created at the center of the disc and the rim (because that is the point of contact?) and that creates an electrical polarity depending on the direction of rotation so since it is rotating downwards it goes to the brush Y ?

Comment: I have added some notes about the eddy currents hope this helps.

Comment: not really sorry :\ can you just tell me the direction of the eddy currents in the disk? I think I can work my way from there.

Comment: Eddy currents (also called Foucault currents[1]) are circular electric currents induced within conductors by a changing magnetic field in the conductor, due to Faraday's law of induction. Eddy currents flow in closed loops within conductors, in planes perpendicular to the magnetic field.